# Which Identity does CodeFluentUser.Current use?

Tags: codefluent

Which Identity does `CodeFluent.Runtime.CodeFluentUser.Current` use?
Does it use `HttpContext.Current.User.Identity` or `Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity`?
Or does it use a fallback mechanism?

Answer (score 0):

`CodeFluentUser.Current` calls `CodeFluentUser.Get(CodeFluentUserIdentityType.CurrentOrWindows)`. If you use `CodeFluentContext.User`, the identity type can be set in the configuration file (by default `userIdentityType="AspNetOrWindows"`)

Here's the documentation for each `CodeFluentUserIdentityType`:

- **`Windows`**: `WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent()`
- **`AspNet`**: `HttpContext.Current.User` when http context is available; `CodeFluentUserIdentityType.Windows` otherwise
- **`AspNetOrWindows`**: `HttpContext.Current.User` when http context is available and user is authenticated; `CodeFluentUserIdentityType.Windows` otherwise
- **`Current`**: `Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity`
- **`CurrentOrWindows`**: `Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity` when authenticated; `CodeFluentUserIdentityType.Windows` otherwise

Answer (score 0):

According to your answer AspNet means:
`HttpContext.Current.User` when http context is available; `CodeFluentUserIdentityType.Windows` otherwise

However, according to the documentation AspNet means:

> If the context is ASP.NET, HttpContext.Current.User.Identity will be
>   used. Otherwise, Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity will be used.

I assume the documentation is right about this?